# Dracula JS : Click event on a node in dracula js Graph library

Tags: javascript, graph

I would like to handle a click event on a node with dracula JS,
the node is added using this code :

```
g.addNode(capability, {render:render});
```

Any suggestion please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that DraculaJS has a problem with event handling, so I would resolve the problem by using [CytoscapeJS](http://js.cytoscape.org/), I found it to be easier, efficient and well documented.